Changes Custom connectors causing import issues in pre-prod
So I am building a Power Apps application using mostly out of the box functionality however have had to create a couple of custom connectors to pull in the data.
I ran into an issue when deploying the solutions to pre-prod environment. In the main solution we have two custom connectors for ingesting data from Databricks. When you import this solution into a new environment (e.g. test, pre-prod or prod) you'll be asked to create connections for both connectors on the target environment. This is where we enter Service Principal data to connect.
When I imported the solution to Test environment, it all went good and I had no issues. However when I try to import the solution into Pre-prod environment I can only create connection for one of them not the both! Although the connections to both is identical, but Power Apps doesn't let me to create a connection for the second connector. All I get is a red exclamation mark with absolutely no clue whatsoever.
Previously they worked fine through all the environments (which they had been built individually in) however, recently they have been updated to read authentication from PAT Token to Service Principal. This update is the only reason I can think that its no longer working but I cant see why as the connectors are identical! Once calls the first chunk of data with the number of other chunks that need to be called and the second connector calls the rest of it.
I did a few hours of research into documentation and Googled the issue, but I had no luck. I reached out to my colleagues and nobody can suggest a remedy for this. I have rebuilt the connector twice to see if there was a bug in the build and the second one still errors but the first one imports with no issue.
Can anyone help?
